# Stop PHP scripts being able to read files in other virtual host's directory

Tags: php, apache-2.4

Okay, so let's say I have two virtual hosts in my Apache config. One defines the directories and such for example.com, whilst the other is for second.org. The server root for apache is `/var/www/` and the document roots for the two servers are `var/www/example` and `var/www/second` respectively. If a PHP script sat inside of `var/www/example`, it could read the entire system files. It could also read and execute anything inside of the `/var/www/` directory. This means a script on example.com could be used to run or read a script on second.org.

I'd like to be able to lockdown each virtual host so that each PHP script can only read /var/www/virtualdomain directory. Kind of like a shared hosting server where if you attempt to run a script such as:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/var/www/otheruser';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally two ways of handling this:

- Running your PHP process as a separate user.
- Configure PHP to keep within its document-root.

Both have its disadvantages.

[Securing PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php) will allow you to set a [documet_root](http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.doc-root.php) where a vhost should operate in while enabling PHP's Safe Mode feature. A slightly more dynamic configuration is to use [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) (which can be used without Safe Mode) but relies on a correct apache configuration. I don't think any of these configurations are a great securty feature because it does not account for external libraries and makes security dependent on the PHP implementation, not the operating system.

Running PHP as a separate user using Apache will require a third-party module or a specific configuration. Usually PHP is build as a module within Apache, so all PHP scripts run as the same user as the webserver. A module like [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) or [mod_ruid](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-ruid/) will drop a process from root specific user and continue the request. This will require running apache as root and compilation of some modules, not to mention a possible security hole. I would not recommend these setups.

You can also switch to PHP-FPM using [mod_fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html) or [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html). This will require you to setup a PHP-FPM 'pool' for every user you would like to give one or more vhosts. PHP-FPM will run as this specific user and will be set to the specific privileges on startup. You can also make specific PHP (ini) configuration settings for each PHP-FPM pool.

Comment: You could also mention *open_basedir*. *mod_proxy_fcgi* is a valid solution although a little tricky to setup, you can use *mod_fastcgi* in external server mode instead. +1 for PHP-FPM solution, this not only lets to separate permissions and ini configuration, but also specific resources per web application.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz: good comments, I have added these!

Comment: I added `php_admin_value open_basedir` followed by the document root to one of my virtual host blocks then did a test to see if PHP could read any files outside of the document root and it returned nothing. I am assuming using `php_admin_value open_basedir` could be a good way to go about this then? Unless of course htaccess can override it, in which case I'll try another solution of yours c:

Comment: You cannot set (nor override) *php_admin_value* config from *.htaccess* nor *ini_set()*, so it's OK. Also remember to use *disable_functions* to block *dl()*, *exec()*, *shell_exec()*, *passthru()*, *proc_open()*, *popen()* and all other functions to load or execute external binaries. Even better - using *open_basedir* restrict PHP access to only include filesystems mounted with *noexec* option (you're on UNIX-family system, I'm guessing).

Answer (score 1):

Run the php processes for each vost in a separate user context and set the filesystem permissions appropriately.